# Should be quoted the names in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

At creating tables and initial data, should be quoted all table names and column names by default?

i.e., for MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (`address_id` INT PRIMARY KEY, `street` TEXT);
```

vs

```
CREATE TABLE address (address_id INT PRIMARY KEY, street TEXT);
```

Comment: Not required if there is no gap between two words. for example, if u have column name with space between two words i.e "Street address", quotation required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No** (*it is optional in your case*), only escape the column names which has space in between or the name you are using is a **[MySQL Reserved Word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**.

Example

```
CREATE TABLE `ADD`
(
    `CASE` VARCHAR(50),
    `FROM` DATETIME,
    `TO` DATETIME,
    `Person Name` VRCHAR(50)
);
```

Comment: Only exception is when generating code: it's easiest to simply quote all column and table names.

Comment: @JensSchauder I agree with you. But in my case i usually don't use restricted words as I don't like to see backticks on my query. hehe